# Swift: Passing { $0.property } as a closure

Tags: swift, generics

Playground Code is below.

Question I have is for the following line:

```
let recentItemsVC = ItemsViewController(items: recentItems, cellDescriptor: {$0.cellDescriptor })
```

I know `ItemsViewController` takes a closure for `cellDescriptor`, but can't wrap my head around what `{$0.cellDescriptor}` by itself means.  There is no `filter`, `map`, `compactMap`, `filter`, etc. called here.

**Two questions:**

**1.  Playground shows (4 times).  What does that mean?**

[image]

**2.  What does passing `{ $0.cellDescriptor }` by itself mean?**

Code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


struct Album {
    var title: String
}

struct Artist {
    var name: String
}


struct CellDescriptor {
    let cellClass: UITableViewCell.Type
    let reuseIdentifier: String
    let configure: (UITableViewCell) -> ()

    init<Cell: UITableViewCell>(reuseIdentifier: String, configure: @escaping (Cell) -> ()) {
        self.cellClass = Cell.self
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
        self.configure = { cell in
            configure(cell as! Cell)
        }
    }
}

final class ItemsViewController<Item>: UITableViewController {
    var items: [Item] = []
    let cellDescriptor: (Item) -> CellDescriptor
    var didSelect: (Item) -> () = { _ in }
    var reuseIdentifiers: Set<String> = []

    init(items: [Item], cellDescriptor: @escaping (Item) -> CellDescriptor) {
        self.cellDescriptor = cellDescriptor
        super.init(style: .plain)
        self.items = items
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        didSelect(item)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        let descriptor = cellDescriptor(item)

        if !reuseIdentifiers.contains(descriptor.reuseIdentifier) {
            tableView.register(descriptor.cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: descriptor.reuseIdentifier)
            reuseIdentifiers.insert(descriptor.reuseIdentifier)
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: descriptor.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        descriptor.configure(cell)
        return cell
    }
}


final class ArtistCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

final class AlbumCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .value2, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


let artists: [Artist] = [
    Artist(name: "Prince"),
    Artist(name: "Glen Hansard"),
    Artist(name: "I Am Oak")
]

let albums: [Album] = [
    Album(title: "Blue Lines"),
    Album(title: "Oasem"),
    Album(title: "Bon Iver")
]

enum RecentItem {
    case artist(Artist)
    case album(Album)
}

let recentItems: [RecentItem] = [
    .artist(artists[0]),
    .artist(artists[1]),
    .album(albums[1])
]

extension Artist {
    func configureCell(_ cell: ArtistCell) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
    }
}

extension Album {
    func configureCell(_ cell: AlbumCell) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
    }
}

extension RecentItem {
    var cellDescriptor: CellDescriptor {
        switch self {
        case .artist(let artist):
            return CellDescriptor(reuseIdentifier: "artist", configure: artist.configureCell)
        case .album(let album):
            return CellDescriptor(reuseIdentifier: "album", configure: album.configureCell)
        }
    }
}

let recentItemsVC = ItemsViewController(items: recentItems, cellDescriptor: {$0.cellDescriptor })


let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: recentItemsVC)

nc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nc.view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AFAIK *4 times* is the count of `recentItems` + 1
2. `{$0.cellDescriptor}` is a closure. Its signature is `@escaping (Item) -> CellDescriptor`. that means that it takes a generic type `Item` and returns a `CellDescriptor`. In this case, for each element of `recentItems` it will return that element's `cellDescriptor`. Whether it's an artist or an album, `cellDescriptor` is defined by this part of the code:

   extension RecentItem {
       var cellDescriptor: CellDescriptor {
           switch self {
           case .artist(let artist):
               return CellDescriptor(reuseIdentifier: "artist", configure: artist.configureCell)
           case .album(let album):
               return CellDescriptor(reuseIdentifier: "album", configure: album.configureCell)
           }
       }
   }

Which sets the `reuseIdentifier` and configures the cell by setting `textLabel?.text` to be either the artist's name or the title of the album.

Answer (score 1):

it's that line of code:

```
    init(items: [Item], cellDescriptor: @escaping (Item) -> CellDescriptor) {
```

You initialize the `ItemsViewController` with an array of `Item` and a callback method. The callback methods accepts an `Item` as parameter. And `Item` has a property named `cellDescriptor`

Comment: Thanks.  By passing `{ $0.cellDescriptor }` is the same as `recentItems.forEach{$0.cellDescriptor }` ?  Playground is throwing `Cannot convert value of type () to expected argument type `(...)-> CellDescriptor`. I am guessing it's not.

Comment: Yes and no. You just pass a function. `$0` is just the first argument of that function. Your error message tells you that this function has to return a CellDescriptor. If you have only one statement in a closure function, that will also be the result. So `{ $0.cellDescriptor }` means: "Take the first argument of the function, and return its property named `cellDescriptor`"